# How do I get Shiny setInputValue to change dropdown selection?

Tags: shiny

These species links change the underlying value of `species` but the dropdown doesn't change. How can I fix this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(iris)
iris %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Species=as.character(actionLink(paste0('button_',Species), label = Species, onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ))) -> iris


shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('set_species', function(value) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('species', value, {priority: 'event'});
    });"),
    selectInput("species",label = "Species",choices=c("setosa","virginica","versicolor")),
    DT::dataTableOutput("data")
  ),

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(iris[c(1,75,150),], escape = FALSE, selection = 'none')
    })

    observeEvent(input$select_button, {
      selectedspecies <- strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2]
      print(selectedspecies)
      session$sendCustomMessage("set_species", selectedspecies)
    })

  }
)
```

Comment: why use a sendCustomMessage and setInputValue? Is this specifically to practice the use of javascript? Whats the desired result?

Comment: no, if you have a more elegant solution I am open to it

Comment: whats the desired result when the user clicks on a link in the table?

Comment: to change the dropdown selection and the underlying value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below will change the select input when the link is pressed. It will also filter the dataset based on what is selected. We can use `updateSelectInput` to achieve this, no need for custom messages.

Also note that `setInputValue` does not set the value of a `selectInput`. It is an alias for `onInputChange`.

> (Note: if you have heard of a function called Shiny.onInputChange, that’s just an older, more confusing name for Shiny.setInputValue; the latter was introduced in Shiny v1.1. Despite never being officially documented or supported, Shiny.onInputChange was/is widely used and we’re not likely to remove it anytime soon, and its behavior is identical to Shiny.setInputValue.)

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

data(iris)
iris <- iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Species = as.character(
    actionLink(
      paste0("button_", Species),
      label = Species,
      onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id);'
    )
  ))

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "species",
      label = "Species",
      choices = c("All", "setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
    textOutput("myText")
  ),

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
      data <- iris
      if (input$species != "All") {
        data <- data %>%
          filter(grepl(input$species, Species))
      }
      DT::datatable(data, escape = FALSE, selection = "none")
    })

    observeEvent(input$select_button, {
      selectedspecies <- strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2]
      print(selectedspecies)
      updateSelectInput(session, "species", selected = selectedspecies)
    })
  }
)
```